# Notation for any element in a set of n elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

In a set of $n$ elements, it is more common to denote $x_n$ as any element of the set, or should I define another index for it (for example, $m \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$ and use $x_m$)? Thanks.

Comment: Why not just $x$?

Comment: I would find $x_n$ *very* confusing.  I'd assume you meant to imply some ordering, of which $x_n$ was the last element.  For sets of natural numbers, as here, I prefer $i,j,k, \dots$ as variables.  To me, $x$ denotes a continuous variable.  Personal preference, of course.

Comment: You should use a different index. Also, I would reccomend giving the set a Name. If it's elements are of the form $x_i$, refer to the set, as X.

Comment: It would be much more useful for you (I think), if you gave one or two specific examples of statements you wish to make. Then we can help you without guesswork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usual practice in my experience is to use lowercase based on the set. It can be any other letter as others pointed out.

For instance, if $S=\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ then $s \in S$.
Side note: some authors even denote this as $S=[n]$ and as $S(n)$.

Keep in mind that this is an unordered set, so indices are not really specified unless you have an indexing order (as in $S=(1,2,3,...,n)$ ) in which case you may say $s_i=i$ $\forall i \in \{1,2,3,...,n\}$ as it is usually done for vector coordinates.